# Can i test color buttons and font style using appium for android and ios app with mac?

Tags: android, macos, appium, inspector, recorder

I'm wondring if i can test colors of buttons comparing wwith the expected rgba color code given in the specification document of the project with appium inspector?

Comment: no this is not possible using appium

Comment: Inspector Button looks like a searh icon Launches the Appium Inspector.

Comment: @ Gaurav : is there an other solution ?